# Where can I report my Social Security retirement benefit from form SSA-1042S in the form 1040NR?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, social-security, income-tax-refund

I started receiving my retirement benefits from SSA last October 2019 after 2 years of processing time. They paid me a large sum corresponding to all months (25) of back pay and I received also my payments from October to December. All these payments had federal income tax withheld to 25% which amounted to a large sum that I want to have refunded.

My question is that I do not see in what line of form 1040nr I should report the income.  In the form shows where I should attach the form SSA-1042S but in that area only show lines for the form 1042S and not SSA-1042S.

Answer (score 1):

Boy you're fast; both forms 1040NR (see next) were only released a few weeks ago, and the instructions still aren't out -- although they shouldn't change much from the 2018 ones.

On 1040NR (*not* -EZ) Social Security is reported on line 8 of schedule NEC (on page 4) [as instructed here](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040nr#idm139700347116960) (link may break when they post 2019, if so look at top left for "Schedule NEC" then "Line 8").